# My Wordpress was hacked, many 404 link increase

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress site, and it was hacked. I already use Wordfence to scan and fix the malicious file that get modified by hacker and change my ftp password already. It seem to be clean now. But I see that google search console tool alert me with the increase of 404 Page not found.

So my question is what should I do to stop this invalid link that cause 404 page not found. These link are something like this:

http://example.com/property-feature/lawn/morning-146-59.html

http://example.com/baby-3990-53.html

Comment: you still have invalid slinks on the site?

Comment: if there is any error you must ask for a backup to the server and already works again or seeking malicious code in folders who also happened to me this

Answer (score 0):

In my experience many WordPress hacks involve scripts that run on innocuous looking urls that perform malicious tasks, such as sending spam email. Once infected, automated scripts from other servers hit these urls to active the scripts.

It is common for these urls to then return 404 errors after you have cleaned the hack.

It is important that you ensure these urls are not in any sitemaps and resubmit correct sitemaps to Google for reprocessing.